# Accessing USGS Map Tiles

Tags: tiles, tile-map-service, usgs

I'm developing a Windows desktop app that uses map tile servers to display a scrollable map. It currently supports OpenStreetMap, OpenTopoMap and Bing Maps. I'm looking to see if there is a service available that offers access to USGS topographic maps.

I've spent quite a bit of time reading up on the REST API specs USGS publishes but I keep stumbling over things like "okay, but what's the base URL?" and "how do I get the developer account that appears to be necessary?"

This leads me to believe that perhaps USGS itself does not host a tile server and that I would need to subscribe to a 3rd party vendor to gain access to their tile server using USGS data/imagery.

Is that correct?

If so, I'd be interested in some recommendations.

I've also read about USGS' The National Map project. It seems like it might offer a USGS-hosted tile server, at least down to some modest scale. But, again, I'm stumbling over how to access its tile server (assuming I'm correct and there is such a beast hosted by USGS).

Comment: This one? https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer

Answer (score 1):

For Tiles using the OGC WMTS API, the end point is either:

`https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/`

for the `<ows:Value>RESTful</ows:Value>` version

Example request like:

`https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/USGSTopo/default/default028mm/3/6/5`

[image: Example WMTS request]

or:

`https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/WMTS?`

for the `<ows:Value>KVP</ows:Value>`

Example (comparable) request like:

`https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/WMTS?service=WMTS&request=GetTile&version=1.0.0&style=default&format=image/png&layer=USGSTopo&TileMatrixSet=default028mm&TileMatrix=3&TileRow=6&TileCol=5&`

[image: Example WMTS request]

The hypermedia document describing the operations for this service is:

https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

Comment: Is there such a URL for 3DEP data?  This format works, but not in Osmand: `https://elevation.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/3DEPElevation/ImageServer/WMSServer?FORMAT=image/png32&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=3DEPElevation:Hillshade%20Multidirectional&STYLES=&CRS=EPSG:3857&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&BBOX=-8256270,5033681,-8255813,5033988`

Comment: Not as far as I can tell: https://elevation.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/3DEPElevation/ImageServer

Answer (score 0):

The url can be used to retrieve

> https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer
>
> "USGS Topo is a tile cache base map service that combines the most
> current data in The National Map (TNM), and other public-domain data,
> into a multi-scale topographic reference map. Data themes included are
> Boundaries, Geographic Names, Transportation, Contours, Hydrography,
> Land Cover, Shaded Relief, and Bathymetry. This service is designed to
> provide a seamless view of TNM data in a geographic information system
> (GIS) accessible format."

In QGIS using **ArcGIS REST Servers** connection

[image]